# Did Select method in Table View not Working in Swift

Tags: tableview, swift4

I'm using two table view in one view controller to populate my different data. All the other delegates methods are working fine but didselect method is not performing an action neither its printing any value in console. I hae checked through story board also all the things looks fine and i have set its delegate and datasources methods also but still it isn't working. Searched a lot from net but still unsuccessful in it. My code is this,

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

    self.searchBar.delegate = self
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(LoginViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    dishDetailTableView.delegate = self
    dishDetailTableView.dataSource = self
    self.addOnTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    addOnTableView.delegate = self
    addOnTableView.dataSource = self
    dishDetailTableView.reloadData()

    sectionArray = [String(MenuService.instance.subCategoryModelInstance[0].sub_categoryName)]
    print(sectionArray)


    cancelBtn.cornerButton()
    cancelBtn.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0.03742904276, alpha: 1)
    cancelBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    nextBtn.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.09759091236, green: 0.5779017098, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    nextBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    nextBtn.cornerButton()
    menuTypeLbl.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    addOnView.borderView(view: addOnView)
    addOnView.isHidden = true
    shadowView.isHidden = true

}
extension DishDetailViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    var count:Int?
    if tableView == dishDetailTableView {
        count =  MenuService.instance.subCategoryItemModelInstance.count
    }
    if (tableView == addOnTableView) {
        count =  AddOnService.instance.AddOnModelInstance.count
    }
    return count!
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    var cell:UITableViewCell?
    if tableView == dishDetailTableView{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "menuCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuDetailTableViewCell

    cell.titleLbl?.text = MenuService.instance.subCategoryItemModelInstance[indexPath.row].itemName
    cell.descriptionLbl?.text = MenuService.instance.subCategoryItemModelInstance[indexPath.row].itemdescription
    cell.priceLbl?.text = MenuService.instance.subCategoryItemModelInstance[indexPath.row].itemprice
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
    }

    if tableView == addOnTableView{

         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AddOnTableViewCell


        cell.addOnLbl.text = AddOnService.instance.AddOnModelInstance[indexPath.row].itemName
        print(cell.addOnLbl?.text! as Any)

        return cell
    }

    return cell!
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if tableView == dishDetailTableView{
        print("Hi")
        dishDetailTableView.reloadData()
    }

    if tableView == addOnTableView {
        print("Hello")
        addOnTableView.reloadData()
    }
}




func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    var count : Int?
    if tableView == dishDetailTableView{
    count = 120
    }
    if tableView == addOnTableView{
       count = 60
    }
    return CGFloat(count!)
}
```

}

How can i perform any action on cell?

Comment: In your extension delegate, call : UITableView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource. call override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { }